# $H(M)$ necessarily highly non-integrable, i.e. forms contact structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let$$M^{2n - 1} = \{z \in \textbf{C}^n : \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}, \textbf{z}) \equiv \textbf{z} \cdot \overline{\textbf{z}} = \textbf{1}\}$$be the unit sphere in $\textbf{C}^n$. Consider the real-codimension one hyperplane field$$H_z(M) \equiv z^{\perp_h} \subset T_z(M) \equiv z^{\perp_{\text{Re}\,h}}.$$Is $H(M)$ necessarily highly non-integrable, i.e. forms a contact structure?

Comment: Yes, it is well-known that this defines a contact structure on $M^{2n-1}$ when $n>1$, as is easily explicitly computable by direct calculation.